# exporting from 3ds Max to XNA

Tags: export, 3dsmax, 3d-modelling, 3d-model

I have created some 3Ds model in 3Ds Max , however after I exported as FBX file and loading it to XNA the models rendered without any mapping and textures from 3Ds Max ?

could someone know hoe to export those mapping and textures?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it just right now. Before you render your texture you need to "bake" it. here is how you do it.http://www.delta3d.org/article.php?story=20051115140557167&topic=tutorials follow this until you make the texture bake. I advice you to do this with a simple color adding using material editor before going to use your own texture. After adding the color do that baking thing!. After you get a .tga file put it into the Texture folder in your project. Also while the model is having the texture or color on it, export it to the Models folder in your project. Now .fbx file has a reference to the .tga file. Add a comment if you fail...

cheers..